# How do i set up a mysql db structure with variable columns?

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures, one-to-many

I'm making a blog where a post has a variable amount of text fields. So it could have 1 or maybe 30. The problem is that i'm not sure what the best practice is for setting up the database. To fix this problem I'm using a one-to-many relationship.

This is how my current database structure looks like now:

posts table:

```
posts
- id
- title
```

post text table:

```
post_text
- id
- post_id
- text
```

And my pivot table:

```
post_text
- post_id
- post_text_id
```

This is what i can think of. Another way would be to give the post table up to the max amount of columns for the text. But this would result in a lot of empty columns as they wouldn't all be used. But i find the method i'm using a bit over complicated?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have variable number of columns in MySQL as you have to define the schema beforehand which cannot be changed later.

If you are not set on using MySQL, you can try out some NoSQL DB like MongoDB which fits well with your use case.

Comment: I see, i'm not familiar with these database structures but I'll check them out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's essential that your post needs multiple text entries, the one to many relationship is the correct way to approach the problem. The only suggestion I would have for you is that your table names could be improved to something more indicative.

As an example:

> ```
> posts
> post_text_fields
> text_fields_in_post
> ```

whilst this method may appear "over-complicated" it's actually the simplest solution when using MySQL to establish a one-to-many relationship.

Alternatively to MySQL are NoSQL solutions that were previously mentioned by @demolisher in their answer, these solutions tend to be oriented around more usable table structure like JSON and may be better suited to an application that requires a weak schema. In this area I too would recommend MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.7 supports a [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html), so you can now store semi-structured data along with your regular schema.

But I don't understand your problem. If you have a one-to-many relationship between posts and post_test, then you don't need multiple text columns, you just need to store multiple *rows* for each post, with one text per row.

I have no idea what your third table is for. It has the same name as post_text, and you don't need it for a one-to-many relationship. You might need it for a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Your right. That should be te right approach. Overthinking fault on my part as I don't actually need a pivot table. The text fields are post exclusive